# deploy website without source code

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have developed website in php. I want deploy it without source code. Is it possible with php?

Can I convert my website code to some intermediate form and then deploy it ?

Comment: its not possible in php ... also why you want to do that ?

Comment: Do you want to hide the *PHP* code, or the *HTML* code?

Comment: Can you elaborate? Do you want to get the resulting HTML from every PHP file?

Comment: @DCoder PHP will be visible?? :), HTML can be hidden??

Comment: Also... *why* do you want to do this? Do you want to prevent people stealing your code?

Comment: php code.And if possible html also. But ultimatly browser will look for html code

Comment: I have developed small utility for store management. I am going to deploy it in local store. I dont want anybody just copy paste  it.

Comment: @deepak: Make a contract and tell your customer which rights they have with the software and how much money they owe you if they break the contract. Works better.

Comment: @roXon: it depends on the use case. The hosting company (and depending on the hosting setup, other users of the same hosting server) can see the PHP code. Site visitors can see the HTML code.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the Zend guard to encode your code so it can't be reverse engineered...

http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/

Answer (score 4):

PHP HTML and JavaScript are open source language so you can do nothing to encode them which can't be decode. One way is [Zend Guard - Encode Your PHP Applications](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/) for php which can be decoded by sites like these: [Websites for zend decoder online.](http://digsitevalue.org/k/zend-decoder-online)

> But the good news is if you always use the last version of Zend Guard
>   it can't be reversed, because still there is no decoder came for it.

Another way is, you buy a [VPS (Virtual private server)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server) or [Dedicated Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedicated_hosting_service) and deploy your source code in there and you just sell your web application usage to your customers (not the source code). So just, you have the user and password of host and no one can see your application code.

---

**Update**
Recently, I've used [ionCube](http://www.ioncube.com/). It's fine. However you need to change your deployment process a bit. Before transferring code to deployment server you need to encrypt it by ionCube. After that you should install ionCube loaders on the server by which php can load the encrypted codes.

Comment: **+1 for selling it as a service advice.** That's the really secure method :)

Answer (score 1):

if you are going to host your website on shared hosting or any thirdparty hosting, you may use zend encoder or ioncube php encoder, they will protect your source code.

[http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/)

http://www.ioncube.com/sa_encoder.php