# Deploy a php application

Tags: php, symfony, deployment

Is there a method to deploy a PHP/Symfony2 project without having to give customer the source code to?

I don't know if it's like JEE project but all my research I found that the only way to deploy a symfony application is by changing dev into prod.

Can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/198864/deploy-php-project-without-giving-away-the-source-code) you have the same question, not about symfony per se but about PHP. Some of the recommendations there:

> - Make a virtual machine appliance (restricts access to code, makes sure that the deployment environment is stable and controlled, and sandboxes the install)
> - If you're afraid they will steal and resell your code, change you and do the support with another person, etc., you could add clauses to the contract forbidding that

Edit: you also have [Zend Guard](http://www.zend.com/en/products/zend-guard) (found it in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739631/deploy-website-without-source-code)), but there usually exists a way to decode the obfuscated PHP code.

Comment: thanks a lot for your unsewer @matiaslaporte .. I took time before returning to this question .. can you please explain to me what do you mean by **virtual machine appliance** ?

Comment: @akino a [virtual machine appliance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_appliance) is "a pre-configured virtual machine image, ready to run on a hypervisor" and "are intended to eliminate the installation, configuration and maintenance costs associated with running complex stacks of software". e.g., you create a virtual machine with virtualbox, configure everything (apache, mysql, etc.)  that the app needs, export the VM as an ovf file, and give it to the client. They will be able to access the app via web, but they won't see the files

Comment: Thank you very much @matiaslaporte